# How to search for a string inside an object and replace it with another value on a condition

Tags: json, jq

I have a Json file with below content, I am trying to replace serviceName string from *ca-visual-node* to *ca-visual-node-canary*  if host name matches **test4.analytics.io** using jq utility. How can I get this done so that we will have json file updated with replace string

```
{
    "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
    "kind": "Ingress",
    "metadata": {
        "annotations": {
            "alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect": "{\"Type\": \"redirect\", \"RedirectConfig\": { \"Protocol\": \"HTTPS\", \"Port\": \"443\", \"StatusCode\": \"HTTP_301\"}}"
     },
        "finalizers": [
            "ingress.k8s.aws/resources"
        ],
        "name": "ca-visual",
        "namespace": "cloud-anaytics",
    },
    "spec": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "host": "test.analytics.io",
                "http": {
                    "paths": [
                        {
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "ca-visual-play",
                                "servicePort": 9443
                            },
                            "path": "/apii/*",
                            "pathType": "ImplementationSpecific"
                        },
                        {
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "ssl-redirect",
                                "servicePort": "use-annotation"
                            },
                            "path": "/*",
                            "pathType": "ImplementationSpecific"
                        },
                        {
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "ca-visual-node",
                                "servicePort": 443
                            },
                            "path": "/*",
                            "pathType": "ImplementationSpecific"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "host": "test4.analytics.io",
                "http": {
                    "paths": [
                        {
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "ca-visual-play",
                                "servicePort": 9443
                            },
                            "path": "/apii/*",
                            "pathType": "ImplementationSpecific"
                        },
                        {
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "ssl-redirect",
                                "servicePort": "use-annotation"
                            },
                            "path": "/*",
                            "pathType": "ImplementationSpecific"
                        },
                        {
                            "backend": {
                                "serviceName": "ca-visual-node",
                                "servicePort": 443
                            },
                            "path": "/*",
                            "pathType": "ImplementationSpecific"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": {
        "loadBalancer": {
            "ingress": [
                {
                    "hostname": "16b3-cloudanaytics.us-xxxx-1.elb.amazonaws.com"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to replace serviceName string from *ca-visual-node* to *ca-visual-node-canary*  if host name matches **test4.analytics.io** using jq utility. How can I get this done so that we will have json file updated with replace string.

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: I tried using jq -r .spec.rules[] with matching filter, it's replacing value but in the output I need whole content along with matching content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just walk the path from the root and use the update operator `|=` with the filter wrapped around `(..)`

```
( 
  .spec.rules[]                             | 
  select(.host == "test4.analytics.io")?    | 
  .http.paths[].backend                     | 
  select(.serviceName == "ca-visual-node")? |
  .serviceName
)  |= "ca-visual-node-canary"
```

<sup>[jqplay - demo](https://jqplay.org/s/5WeffO4PAK)</sup>

Comment: worked perfectly |= did the trick for me. Thanks a ton.